# Bootstrap sign in form integrated with Devise not not creating new user session

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, devise

I found a nice looking [bootstrap](http://bootsnipp.com/snippets/featured/login-amp-signup-forms-in-panel) sign in form for my rails app that is using the [Devise](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise) gem.
I converted the rails `form_for` Helper to straight HTML using the Bootstrap classes.

***Original form***

```
<%= form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: session_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :email %><br />
    <%= f.email_field :email, autofocus: true %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :password %><br />
    <%= f.password_field :password, autocomplete: "off" %>
  </div>

  <% if devise_mapping.rememberable? %>
    <div class="field">
      <%= f.check_box :remember_me %>
      <%= f.label :remember_me %>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit "Log in" %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

***Form_for converted to HTML:***

```
 <div class="container">
        <div id="loginbox" style="margin-top:50px;" class="mainbox col-md-6 col-md-offset-3 col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-2">
            <div class="panel panel-info" >
                    <div class="panel-heading">
                        <div class="panel-title">Sign In</div>
                        <div style="float:right; font-size: 80%; position: relative; top:-10px"><a href="/users/password/new">Forgot password?</a></div>
                    </div>

                    <div style="padding-top:30px" class="panel-body" >

                        <div style="display:none" id="login-alert" class="alert alert-danger col-sm-12"></div>

                        <form action="/users/sign_in" id="new_user" class="form-horizontal" role="form" method="post">

                            <div style="margin-bottom: 25px" class="input-group">
                                        <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i></span>
                                        <input id="user_email" type="email" class="form-control" name="user[email]" value="" placeholder="email">
                                    </div>

                            <div style="margin-bottom: 25px" class="input-group">
                                        <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-lock"></i></span>
                                        <input id="user_password" type="password" class="form-control" name="user[password]" placeholder="password">
                                    </div>


                            <div class="input-group">
                                      <div class="checkbox">
                                        <label>
                                          <input id="user_remember_me" type="checkbox" name="user[remember_me]" value="1"> Remember me
                                        </label>
                                      </div>
                                    </div>


                                <div style="margin-top:10px" class="form-group">
                                    <!-- Button -->

                                    <div class="col-sm-12 controls action">
                                      <input type="submit" id="btn-login" class="btn btn-success" name="commit" value="Log in">


                                    </div>
                                </div>


                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <div class="col-md-12 control">
                                        <div style="border-top: 1px solid888; padding-top:15px; font-size:85%" >
                                            Don't have an account!
                                        <a href="/users/sign_up" onClick="$('#loginbox').hide(); $('#signupbox').show()">
                                            Sign Up Here
                                        </a>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </form>



                        </div>
                    </div>
        </div>

</div>
```

My problem is that when I click on the login button on the html form: `<input type="submit" id="btn-login" class="btn btn-success" name="commit" value="Log in">` it's not creating a `new_user_session`. Nothing happens except that it redirects me to my index page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default, after signing in a user, confirming the account or updating the password `Devise` redirects to the *root path* of the application, unless specified otherwise. If `index` page is the root path (as you haven't mentioned it in question) then your log in must be successful, i.e., the user session was successfully created. You can also override `after_sign_in_path_for` method in `ApplicationController` to customize your redirect hooks.

For example:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  #..
  def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
    user_profile_path(resource) ## <<-- Specify the path where you want to redirect after sign in
  end
end
```

> My problem is that when I click on the login button on the html form:
>    it's not creating a new_user_session.
>   Nothing happens except that it redirects me to my index page.

I suppose you are expecting a message in this case for sign in success/failure. For that to happen, make sure that you are displaying flash messages in the views as Devise uses flash messages to let the application users know if sign in was successful or failure. Best place to do that is in the layout files.

For example: In `app/views/layouts/application.html.erb`

```
<% flash.each do |name, msg| %>
  <%= content_tag :div, msg %>
<% end %>
```

Another pointer is to add the following code within the sign in form, so that if for some reason the sign in fails, user gets to see the errors on the same page:

```
<%= form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: session_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
  <%#...%>
  <%= devise_error_messages! %> <%# Add this to display error messages %>
  <%#...%>
<%end%>
```

Comment: I apologies if I wasn't clear in my question. When I "click" the log in button devise is not creating a new user session. Previously when I used the `form_for` helper it was working fine. Maybe I am missing something in this html form to properly create a user session. Any help with that?

Comment: @Cyzanfar How do you know its not creating a user session? How are you verifying it? What do you expect the code to do after sign in which was working in your old code and is not working now? This would help in resolving your issue. I would suggest you to add these in the question as an update.

Comment: I know it is not creating a new user session because there is no current_user session after I submit through the log in form. After I sign in, I expect the code to retain the current user session as well as redirect me to the users profile. In any case, none of those two are happening. Therefore I am 100% sure there is no user session created after submitting the post request for the session.

Comment: However I will check your answer as the correct one because it did help me understand my problem and subsequently solve it. Cheers.